# What is the TestStand run time error -17501?

Tags: labview, teststand

I got below teststand run time error.

[image]

When would this error occured?

How to tackle this error?

Can anyone give me an answer?

Comment: NI Forum says that this error happens, when Sequence Editor receives error which it can't handle. It could be buffer overflow, for example. I would recommend to debug "Module Plugins - UUT Done" sequence. Have you modified process model? Or TestStand API? Also, does it happen all the time?

Comment: It happens randomly after almost 200~300 tests.

Comment: One change is to remove report step in PostUUT.

Comment: Then I would assume that you have memory leak. Did you remove it in process model file? Or you have customized PostUUT callback in your client sequence? Maybe you could try to check SeqEdit.exe and LabVIEW.exe memory consumption, to see whether it is increased over time.

Comment: It was the report step in PostUUT callback.

Comment: Was it PostUUT callback of process model file, or it was overriden PostUUT callback of your client sequence? Anyway, check memory consumption. If you have large memory leak - that will be root cause of this error.